# How to query multiple tables using ARQ jena?

Tags: sparql, jena, arq

## Overview

I am using [ARQ](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/) in order to query local `RDF`files. The query is applied on *5* files which are:

- a_m.nt, description.nt, labels.nt, links.nt, literals.nt

Information is modeled as a set of triples:

- subject **predicate** object

---

## Algorithm

First I want to select specific topics from **a_m.nt** file. Second I want to select the labels and descriptions of the selected topics from **description.nt** and **labels.nt**. In another way, search **description.nt** and **labels.nt** for the descriptions and labels that have the same topic as the one that was extract from **a_m.nt**. Finally I want to extract the rest of properties from **links.nt** and **literals.nt**.

---

## Query

```
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?x ?y ?p ?o
where { 
?topic rdf:type music. 
?topic rdf:description ?x.
?topic rdf:label ?y. 
?topic ?p ?o. 
}
```

---

## Command line

```
sparql --data a_m.nt --data description.nt --data label.nt --data links.nt --data literals.nt --query query_sparql
```

---

## questions

By using this query, first I select a topic that have the type `music` then I select its description, label and other properties. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current query, it looks like you don't need all those bindings in the where clause, since you are retrieving everything anyhow with the last statement `?topic ?p ?o`. You need to namespace the `music` variable properly and probably add `DISTINCT` to the select clause. So maybe rewrite the query like this:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>
select DISTINCT ?topic ?p ?o
where { 
  ?topic a :music. 
  ?topic ?p ?o. 
}
```

A possible result may be:

```
<foo> <type> <music>
<foo> <description> "this is foo"
<foo> <label> "foo"
<bar> <type> <music>
<bar> <label> "bar"
```

This is different from the query you have, more general. You basically get everything back that is of type `music` along with all the properties and values associated with them. In your query you only get results back that have some description and label (and are of type `music`), along with all the properties and values that are associated with them:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>
select ?x ?y ?p ?o
where { 
  ?topic rdf:type :music. 
  ?topic rdf:description ?x.
  ?topic rdf:label ?y. 
  ?topic ?p ?o. 
}
```

Think of it as a table with `?x ?y ?p ?o` being the column headers. A possible result may be:

```
"this is foo" "foo" <type> <music>
"this is foo" "foo" <description> "this is foo"
"this is foo" "foo" <label> "foo"
```

etc.

Your query will depend on how your data is organised. My question is, are there any other properties in `description.nt` and `labels.nt` that you want to avoid in the results? If so, then you may want to load that data into a [named graph](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql_datasets.html) and extract only descriptions and labels from that graph in your query. Arbitrary example:

```
SELECT ?a ?b
FROM <A>
FROM NAMED <B>
WHERE
{
  ?x a <foo> .
  GRAPH <B> { ?x ?a ?b }
}
```

Comment: **Is, are there any other properties in description.nt and labels.nt that you want to avoid in the results?**  Actually no. I also want to include them in the final results. From what I understood the query is wrong, that's why you thought that i didn't want to include them.

Comment: By using the graph will I be able to include description, labels, links and literals?

Comment: Your query is not wrong, it just struck to me that you are mixing values and properties in the same result binding, especially when including the last closure that pretty much fetches everything. Using a graph you can isolate certain triples when running your SPARQL. That way you can retrieve description and label for each entity from a named graph and the rest of the bindings from the default graph. That way you are not recapturing desciption and label in `?topic ?p ?o`. That's just one way to do it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better explanation. Hope it helps. It really depends on what you want for each result and how you process each result..